# In VisualForce, is there a way via code to determine whether we are in a Production environment?

Tags: apex, javascript

I'm developing some javascript code that I only want to execute when a Visualforce page is in Production. Is there a simple way to check the running environment via js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can query the "organization" object:

```
[SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organizatino LIMIT 1];
```

We have a class called MiscUtils. In the static initialization code we have the following:

```
static {
    IS_PRODUCTION_ORG = ![SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organization LIMIT 1].IsSandbox;
}
```

This will run the query and get the information and the query only runs once per context so it doesn't chew up your soql queries.

Then in your controller you can do something like this:

```
public Boolean IsProductionOrg {
    get {
        if (IsProductionOrg  == null) {
            IsProductionOrg = MiscUtils.IS_PRODUCTION_ORG;
        }

        return IsProductionOrg;
    }

    set;
}
```

And then you can reference this on your VF page using the normal syntax:

```
{!IsProductionOrg}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [apex:remoteObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_remoteObjects.htm#!) element to to query the Organization object, which from there has a field IsSandbox that you can use to detect if you're in production or not without needing any Apex Code at all.